# Scallion Error -1001

Tags: onion-services

```
mint scallion-gpg # mono scallion/bin/Debug/scallion.exe -l<br>
Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: ErrorCode:'-1001'
at scallion.CLDeviceInfo.CheckError (Int32 err) [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.CLDeviceInfo.GetPlatformIds () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.CLDeviceInfo.GetDeviceIds () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.CLRuntime.GetDevices () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.Program.ListDevices () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: ErrorCode:'-1001'
at scallion.CLDeviceInfo.CheckError (Int32 err) [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.CLDeviceInfo.GetPlatformIds () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.CLDeviceInfo.GetDeviceIds () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.CLRuntime.GetDevices () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.Program.ListDevices () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you're asking and I'm tempted to close this question. Please put some more explanation into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found this ticket on github: https://github.com/lachesis/scallion/issues/30

To sum things up: Check if you have OpenCL installed correctly.

Comment: I saw that too and reinstalled OpenCL. Doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe try using shallot? At least from what I know it is guaranteed to work. I don't really have a idea other than that. Sorry I can't help.